# time is different between javascript date and java date

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to get time from both javascript and java for same timestamp.
But somehow, there is difference.

in Javascript,

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(-27000000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes(); // 0:30
```

in java,

```
final Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(-27000000);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date)); // 12:00 AM
```

If we do proper formatting, javascript result is 12:30 AM whereas java is 12:00 AM.

Comment: One of your pieces of code isn't taking timezone into account, while the other is.

Comment: lan Kemp .. meaning javascript code does not consider timezone ?...